# Show a tick every n value

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

How can I setup an axis that it shows not 5 or 10 or whatever number of ticks but rather show a tick each n units. In this case if a dataset looks like this:

```
[2,3,6,7,10,13,17,20]
```

The ticks will be on `0, 5, 10, 15, 20` if I configure it to show a tick for every 5th step.
How can it be achieved?

Here is a real example I am working on [image: Chart]

I want on x axis show a tick after each 20 years, so it should be not `0, 10, 20, 30, ..., n`, but `0, 20, 40, 60, 80, ..., n`.

For y axis I need values to be 500k stepped, so it should be `0, 500k, 1m, 1.5m, ..., n`.

**Update**

I have found a simple working solution. I call an axis via `.call(yAxis) as usual, then I find go through created ticks and check if their datum has a remainder when I divide their values by the step number I need. If there is no remainder, then I set opacity to 1, otherwise hide them by setting opacity to 0. Here is an example:

```
          yAxisElement
            .selectAll('.tick')
            .style({
              opacity: function (d, i) {
                return d % 500000 ? 0 : 1;
              }
            })
```

It's not an ideal solution, because it can't add the ticks that are in the middle of existing ones by value, like on this image, if I want to use 0, 15, 30, 45 and so on, just show/hide those that are already there. In the case I need to add ticks for other values, I need to make a custom axis or use the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25976922/show-a-tick-every-n-value#comment40676231_25976922) suggested by Lars Kotthoff.

Comment: actually i read your post 3 times and still don't get what you trying to achieve ^^, could you pls explain this a lil bit better ?

Comment: The only way to do this is compute the tick values yourself and set them through `.tickValues()`.